# Getting Error of Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin

Tags: javascript, php

I have created a php page with the code

```
<iframe src ="http://practiceguru.in">
```

but when I run this code then I am getting error in console

```
 Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://practiceguru.in" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
    at http://practiceguru.in/Exam/questionpaper2.aspx?x=180:9:37
```

How can I resolve the error ?